# How to add values of two column to dictionary for mapping

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a data of two column like this

```
data.head()
   GroupId  Planet
0    0008   Europa
1    0008   Europa
2    0009   Mars
3    0010   Earth
4    0011   Earth
5    0012   Earth
6    0012   NaN
```

Planet column has missing values but same groupid shares same planet. How can i create dictionary for mapping to fill na like { '0008' : 'Europa', '0009' : 'Mars ...}

Comment: Hi @Mert, Earth have 10, 11 and 12 as GroupID. How does it share same planet? Also can you add some NaN values in DataFrame?

Comment: Planets and GroupId are not unique, different groups might belong to same planet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need, I have added sample dataframe with `NaN` as per your description -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# dataframe
planet_data = {
    "GroupId": ["0008", "0008", "0009", "0010", "0008", "0011", "0012"],
    "Planet":  ["Europa", "Europa", "Mars", "Earth", np.nan, "Earth", "Earth"]
}

data = pd.DataFrame(planet_data)

# create a dictionary
df = data.copy(deep=True)
df = df.dropna()
df = df.drop_duplicates()
planet_map = dict(zip(df["GroupId"], df["Planet"]))

# replace missing values using dictionary
data["Planet"] = data["GroupId"].apply(lambda x: planet_map.get(x, None))
data
```

Comment: An error occured. It looks like GrupId = '0210' has only one row and it's Planet is NaN. So it gave KeyError: '0210' .  I think it is because we dropped na values so planet_map does not have key '0210' .  Could you help me how can i write do map if key has number we want

Comment: Sure, I have updated the code. Now if the `GroupId` has no corresponding `Planet` it will be set to `None`. If you don't want them in your results you can do `data.dropna()`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['GroupId'], keep='first').set_index('GroupId').to_dict()['Planet']
```